# How to make my query using a self-join faster?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, self-join

I had originally tried creating two different queries and then merging them in R to get a cumulative time graph but I am trying to just get the information I want in a single query.

Original code:

```
users <- dbGetQuery(pool, "select id, name
                    from schema.table
                    where (name like '%t%' and name like '%2018%') or
                    (name like '%t%' and name like '%2017%')")
opts <- dbGetQuery(pool, "select id, name, ts
                    from schema.table
                    where name = 'qr_optin'")

all <- merge(users, opts, by = "id")

all <- all %>% 
  mutate(date =  as.Date(all$ts),
         name.x = gsub("t", "", name.x)) %>% 
  group_by(name.x, date) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
name          date         n 
x          2018-09-09      12
x          2018-09-08      5
y          2018-09-08      4
xy         2018-09-06      8
xy         2018-09-04      9
```

I'm trying to get the information with at least the two queries joined but I've only ever made it this far and it's insanely slow.

```
select f1.id, f1.name, f2.ts
from schema.table f1
left join schema.table f2 on f2.id = f1.id
where f2.name = ' qr_optin' and
(f1.name like '%t%' and f1.name like '%2018%') or
(f1.name like '%t%' and f1.name like '%2017%')
```

Comment: What is *insanely slow*? Postgres query or R import, merge, and aggregation? All you do in R can be handled in Postgres. And why are you doing a self join?

Answer (score 2):

Simply run pure SQL in Postgres either for the merge (i.e., join) or summarise (i.e., aggregregation)

**Join level** query

```
select usrs.id, usrs.name, opts.ts
from schema.table as usrs
inner join rvv.fbm as opts 
        on opts.id = usrs.id and opts.name = 'qr_optin'
where (name like '%t%' and name like '%2018%') or
      (name like '%t%' and name like '%2017%')
```

**Aggregation** query *(with CTE)*

```
with cte as 
  ( 
    select usrs.id, Replace(usrs.name, "t", "") as usr_name, opts.ts
    from schema.table as usrs
    inner join rvv.fbm as opts 
            on opts.id = usrs.id and opts.name = 'qr_optin'
    where (name like '%t%' and name like '%2018%') or
          (name like '%t%' and name like '%2017%')
  )

select cte.usr_name as name, cte.ts as date, count(*) as n
from cte
group by cte.name, cte.ts
```

Pass either query in R into `DBI::dbGetQuery` call.

```r
all <- dbGetQuery(pool, "...myquery...")
```